# How to check whether instance exists for a polymorphic type with Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Suppose, I want to check whether an instance of `Show` exists for type `[a]` (which it does).

If I do this:

```
let t = ListT `AppT` VarT (mkName "a")
$(stringE . show =<< isInstance ''Show [t])
```

I get the following error:

```
Not in scope: type variable `a'
In the argument of reifyInstances: GHC.Show.Show [a]
In the expression: $(stringE . show =<< isInstance ''Show [t])
In an equation for `it':
    it = $(stringE . show =<< isInstance ''Show [t])
```

If I then do this:

```
let t' = ForallT [PlainTV (mkName "a")] [ClassP ''Show [VarT (mkName "a")]] t
$(stringE . show =<< isInstance ''Show [t'])
```

I get

```
"False"
```

Answer (score 3):

What you would like to do is actually *see* the types here before they are splices in. If you are in ghci, you can type `set -ddump-splices` which will print each splice after it is compiled. Then, with your example:

```
>undefined :: $(return t)
<interactive>:27:16-23: Splicing type
    return t ======> [a]
<interactive>:27:16:
    Not in scope: type variable `a'
    In the result of the splice:
      $(return t)

>undefined :: $(return t')
<interactive>:28:16-24: Splicing type
    return t' ======> forall a b. (Show a, Show b) => [a]
```

(The second one also gives an error - but for a different reason. You can have a type variable in the context that is not in the actual type. This error is essentially unrelated to your question).

As you can see the type `[a]` is *not* the same as the type `forall a . [a]`. When you write in (normal) haskell:

```
func :: [a]
```

You are actually writing:

```
func :: forall a . [a]
```

However, Template Haskell doesn't insert `forall`s for you automatically (this would be very undesired behaviour). And the type

```
func :: forall . [a]
```

will give you an error (the `a is not in scope` error) because `a` has not been bound in any visible scope, as one would expect! And the type `forall . [a]` is equivalent to the type generated by TH when you wrote `return $ ListT`AppT`VarT (mkName "a")`.

edit:

If you are willing to just replace type vars with concrete types, then you are essentially just searching the type for your class. I don't know if this is your desired behavior, I guess I am struggling to find a case where this is useful. But if you can easily check if a typeclass instance is present in the context of a type:

```
existentialTypeContainsClass :: Name -> Type -> Bool
existentialTypeContainsClass clss (ForallT _ cxt t) = or $ map (boundByPred clss) cxt

boundByPred :: Name -> Pred -> Bool
boundByPred _ (EqualP _ _)    = False
boundByPred c (ClassP clss _) = c == clss

t = ListT `AppT` VarT (mkName "a")
t' = ForallT [PlainTV (mkName "a")] [ClassP ''Show [VarT (mkName "a")]] t

runTest = existentialTypeContainsClass ''Show t'
```

Comment: You've explained, why the error message appears, however you haven't answered the actual question. I'll remind it: How to check whether instance exists for a polymorphic type with Template Haskell?

Comment: If you have access to the actual `Type` representation, you have to search it yourself for the desired class instance. The behavior you experienced is correct - polymorphic types can't have instances.

Comment: There is an `instance Show a => Show [a]`. Isn't it polymorphic? I want to check whether it exists. So what you're saying is the only thing I can do is downgrade to some specific type, like `[Int]`, right?

Comment: `instance Show a => Show [a]` means that that for all types that are instances of `Show`, a list of that type is also an instance of `Show`. Not that the type `forall a . Show a => [a]` has a `Show` instance! A concrete type has instances, but a polymorphic type with a class constraint is really just promising that an instance exists, not so much possessing it. That is why I can write complete gibberish like `let f = undefined :: (Num (a, a)) => a -> a` and the compiler only complains when I try to instantiate the type - until then, it takes my word for it that the instance exists.

Comment: But depending on your actual usage, you may still be able to recover typeclass information, albiet not 'real' information, but the sort of 'promises' that the writer of the code made. If you have the `Name` of a type, you can `reify` the actual type. It may contain assertions that are false (like `(Num (a, a))`) but I guess you have to trust the user that they wrote working code! From your original question though, it is unclear where you get the `Type` for which it is necessary to determine if it has a `Show` instance.

Comment: I don't need to recover any typeclass information. I know a specific class and I know some rank-n type I need to check an instance for (a list, a tuple), what is unknown are the types of its variables, i.e. as given in the question. So, again, the best I can do is replace the variables with some specific type, which I know an instance of that class exists for, e.g., like `[Int]`? Yes/No? You need to understand that to accept your answer I need it to solve the stated problem or state that it's impossible to solve.

Comment: I tried to address what I think your question is in an edit in my original answer.

Comment: OMG. The misunderstanding seems to be getting farther and farther. I don't need to check contexts, I need to check whether an instance is declared for a type. That's why I'm using `isInstance`, that's why the question states "How to check whether instance exists...".

Answer (score 2):

Why the code in question doesn't work is explained in [answer of *user2407038*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20138236/485115).

Concerning the solution, while the following doesn't completely solve the problem, it can be used as a workaround. The `[a]` can be checked by supplying some specific type instead of variable `a`. You must know some specific existing instances for the class you're checking. In case of `Show` we know that there exists an instance for `Int` - we can use that:

```
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> let t = ListT `AppT` ConT ''Int
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> $(stringE . show =<< isInstance ''Show [t])
"True"
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with GHC 7.10 and Template Haskell 2.10, the
[original code provided by Nikita Volkov](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20136559)
actually works out-of-the-box:

```
> let t = ListT `AppT` VarT (mkName "a")
> $(stringE . show =<< isInstance ''Show [t])
"True"
```

The [answer of Nikita Volkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20155474)
still works on GHC 7.10 and TH 2.10.
It is pretty elegant IMHO,
though I prefer using `TupleT 0` in place of `ConT ''Int`
(just because it is a simpler type):

```
> let t = ListT `AppT` TupleT 0
> $(stringE . show =<< isInstance ''Show [t])
"True"
```

For GHC 7.10 and TH 2.10,
you can use any of the two methods.
For GHC ≤ 7.8 and TH ≤ 2.9,
you should use the second method listed in this answer.

### Further Reading

- [GHC Ticket 6114](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6114): ghc: panic! occurred with use of isInstance, newName and a type splice;
- [GHC Ticket 7066](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7066): isInstance does not work for compound types.